# Passing key events to background activity

Tags: android, android-activity, background

We wanted to route the key events to background activity.
Eg: Let’s assume 2 Activity’s A and B.
First I will launch activity A , on top of activity A I will launch Activity B which is having transparency , So both activity A and B is visible with B being foreground activity.
Now user press any key. The key  is first passed  to Activity B (since it’s a focused activity) , if Activity B doesn’t consume that key event we need to pass that key event to Activity A.

Pls suggest me how can we achive this

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when an Activity is in the background it can no longer process any UI events since the Activity is invisible to the user.  Stated another way, an invisible Activity shouldn't *need* to process events because those events are irrelevant for an invisible Activity.

If you want to process events and get data that both Activities use and can not do so via the `startActivityForResult` and `getActivityResult` methods you should probably start looking at [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Either way you do it, it is simply not necessary for an Activity to process any results or data while it is invisible.  Utilize methods like `onResume`, `onStart`, `onRestart` to process the data you want once the Activity is coming to the foreground.